# How to Select PHP Multidimensional Array items with Checkbox Form

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms

I'm very new to PHP and just code in general, so my apologizes if my code looks like a mess.

I've created a multidimensional array and when certain checkboxes are selected and submitted through the form, I want only the selected arrays items show. Such as, John Smith's information and image only if just he is selected.

Here is my multidimensional array:

```
<?php
$characters = array (

  'john' => 
  array (
    'first_name' => 'John',
    'last_name' => 'Smith',
    'age' => '40',
    'image_url' => 'images/john.png',
  ),
  'jane' => 
  array (
    'first_name' => 'Jane',
    'last_name' => 'Doe',
    'age' => '30',
    'image_url' => 'images/jane.png',
  ),
  'sara' => 
  array (
    'first_name' => 'Sara',
    'last_name' => 'Johnson',
    'age' => '10',
    'image_url' => 'images/sara.png',
  )
)
?>
```

And here is my html form:

```
<h3 class="form__heading"> Select characters to show </h3>
<form method="post">
<ul class="form__items">

<!--John-->
<li class="form__item">
<label for="john">John Smith </label>
<input id="john" type="checkbox" name="john">
</li>
                                        
<!--Jane-->
<li class="form__item">
<label for="jane">Jane Doe </label>
 <input id="jane" type="checkbox" name="jane">
 </li>
                                        
<!--Sara-->
<li class="form__item">
<label for="sara">Sara Johnson </label>
<input id="sara" type="checkbox" name="sara">                           
</li>
</ul>
                                    
<!--Button-->
<input class="form__button" type="submit" value="Show Characters">
</form>
```

I have tried foreach and for loops, but I think I'm just doing it wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: So if you select two list items, only those two's info should be shown?

Comment: Yes! That is what I am hoping to do.

Comment: So what's the issue that you are facing with that?

Comment: I can't figure out the PHP to make the selected list items show when submitting the form.

Comment: Please post your PHP script (apart from the array) - at least show what you have attempted - you mentioned you have tried foreach /looping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved your problem, please checkout the script i giving you below

html code will be like this

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<ul class="form_items">
<!--John-->
<li class="form_item">
<label for="john">John Smith </label>
<input id="john" type="checkbox" name="characters[]" value="john">
</li>                               
<!--Jane-->
<li class="form__item">
<label for="jane">Jane Doe </label>
 <input id="jane" type="checkbox" name="characters[]" value="jane">
 </li>                            
<!--Sara-->
<li class="form_item">
<label for="sara">Sara Johnson </label>
<input id="sara" type="checkbox" name="characters[]" value="sara">                           
</li>
</ul>
```

and php script will be like this

```
    <?php
$characters = array (
    'john' => 
    array (
      'first_name' => 'John',
      'last_name' => 'Smith',
      'age' => '40',
      'image_url' => 'images/john.png',
    ),
    'jane' => 
    array (
      'first_name' => 'Jane',
      'last_name' => 'Doe',
      'age' => '30',
      'image_url' => 'images/jane.png',
    ),
    'sara' => 
    array (
      'first_name' => 'Sara',
      'last_name' => 'Johnson',
      'age' => '10',
      'image_url' => 'images/sara.png',
    )
    );

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $selectedCharacter = $_POST['characters'];
    foreach ($selectedCharacter as $Character) {
        echo "first_name:- ".$characters[$Character]['first_name'].'<br>';
        echo "last_name:- ".$characters[$Character]['last_name'].'<br>';
        echo "age:- ".$characters[$Character]['age'].'<br>';
        echo "image_url:- ".$characters[$Character]['image_url'].'<br><br>';
    }
}
?>
```

refer to this channel https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCnqWFcMpFA_dsxEzt7lKxJA

Comment: Hey, this is a good answer! As OP is new to coding in general, I figured I would explain a bit about what you have done.

The names of the checkboxes have been changed to 'characters[]' this means the posted data will be treated as an array. CodeAlgo has then set the character name as a value in that array. 

In the PHP script, the foreach loop is stepping through that array, using the value as a key to select data from your pre existing $characters array.

Comment: Thank you both so much! This worked for me, I appreciate the help setting me in the right direction. My little project may not look the greatest but at least now it works! :)

Comment: @n1021 please mark accepted if this works for you